# quiero obtener solo la fecha de mis registro de BD de la columna 'created_at'

Tags: laravel-5

¿Como puedo darle formato a la columna `'created_at'` `('Y-m-d')` en el controlador de laravel.

Ya que me muestra `"2018-02-10 00:00:00"`

Tengo esta consulta

```
BD::select('created_at')
```

me muestra

```
"2018-02-10 00:00:00"
```

Comment: y que formato le quieres dar?

Comment: BD::select('created_at')
me muestra "2018-02-10 00:00:00"  solo quiero obtener la fecha

Comment: Buenas tardes yo he usado este paquete, me parece muy útil. https://github.com/briannesbitt/Carbon

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Al incio de tu `Controller` haz lo siguiente

```
use DB;
```

> El código anterior, va a ayudar a invocar al facade `DB` que ayuda a
>   habilitar el uso del query builder para que con ello puedas construir
>   consultas con código SQL en lugar de usar los métodos propios del ORM
>   Eloquent

Posteriormente dentro de la clase y del método que tienes designado para esta query, realiza la siguiente consulta

**código de ejemplo**

Este código es funcional de un ejemplo que yo te hice solo adaptalo al nombre de tu tabla

```
$data = DB::table('users')
        ->selectRaw('DATE(created_at) AS Fecha')
        ->get();

return $data;
```

**Resultado obtenido de la consulta anterior**

```
[
  {
   "Fecha": "2018-10-02"
  },
  {
   "Fecha": "2018-10-02"
  },
  {
   "Fecha": "2018-10-02"
  },
  {
   "Fecha": "2018-10-02"
  }
]
```

Hacemos uso como vez de:

1. `selectRaw()` para poder ejecutar funciones SQL que el ORM no tiene por defecto
2. Con uso de la función `DATE()` le pasamos la columna `created_at` y opcionalmente le asignamos un alias

Answer (score 1):

La palabra "formato" puede darnos problemas a la hora de interpretar tu pregunta.

En general, en un controlador NO DEBERIAS cambiar el formato de los datos que tienes en bbdd. Puede que tengas que operar con ellos, y el controlador es el punto donde hacerlo.

Donde deberias cambiar el formato es en la PRESENTACION (Esto es, en la plantilla correspondiente). Ahi si deberias dar formato a tus datos, para presentarlos como necesites.

En caso de laravel, puedes utilizar Carbon (como indica @Fabio en su respuesta).
En el controlador cojes la fecha

```
$fecha = BD::select('created_at')
```

En tu plantilla blade puedes poner:

```
{{ \Carbon\Carbon::parse($fecha)->format('d/m/Y')}}
```

Comment: Eso es relativo, si no se pudiera cambiar el formato entonces al querer hacer un group concat en el controlador según tú estaría mal, pero encuentro menos lógica hacerlo en la vista

Comment: Y no le está cambiando el formato, de hecho solo toma una parte del valor guardado y eso no es cambiar el formato

Comment: pues por eso mismo. Si esta `tomando` una parte del valor, no es cambiarle el formato. En esencia, si va a operar con ese resultado cambiado, es correcto (porque la operación o el tratamiento de datos se hace en un controller) pero si lo va a mostrar como salida (`formato`), eso es tarea de una vista.

Comment: es relativo, lo esta haciendo desde el controller y es válido desde que el propio SQL permite tomar una sección del dato deseado y al final en la vista solo se manda esa estructura para acomodarla; en todo caso ambas concepciones son correctas